# Disabling empty selectboxes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I disable all select inputs that don't have any options using jQuery? I'm using an .each to access each box, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to combine `this` with a selector to specify the options *within* that `this`.

```
$('select').each(function(){
    if (this 'option').length == 0) {
        $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('select').each(function(){
    if (!this.options.length) this.disabled = true;
});
```

You can also do something like:

```
$('select').prop('disabled', function () {
    return !this.options.length;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/qjr2zr2w/)

You can use this one liner:

```
$('select:not(:has(option))').prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

The context(`this`) is the second argument.

```
$('select').each(function(){
    if ($('option', this).length == 0) {
        this.disabled = true;
    }
})
```

Comment: There's no reason to re-query the DOM for options.

Comment: OP asked how to combine `this` with a selector.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code:

```
$('select').each(function(){
    var noOfOptions = $(this).children('option').size();

    if(noOfOptions == 0){
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'true');
    }
})
```